# LibGDX + JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, libgdx

Есть у меня идея фикс, сделать редактор(ы) используя базовый интерфейс Java.
Я пробовал 2 варианта этой реализации, но пока не преуспел. **Есть ли у кого работающий пример внедрения окна LibGDX в Swing+JavaFX или просто FX?**

А вот то, что я пробовал:

Я пробовал эту библиотеку [LibGDX-FX](https://github.com/Trixt0r/LibGDX-FX), но она или сильно устарела или в обще не работала. Если небольшие различия я поправил, то вот проблему из-за которой набор байт с отрендереной картинкой все время приходит пустой, я не решил. (Уж больно глубоко находится место где его формируют)

LibGDX может из коробки рендерить в awt.Canvas. Увы знаком я в основном с FX а не со Swing, поэтому старался внедрить эту ноду в сцену FX. Внедрить то мне ее получилось (Canvas -> JPanel -> SwingNode), да только картинка так и не появилась.